# fail2ban not blocking access to imap ports

Tags: dovecot, imap, fail2ban

I have a mail server with `dovecot`. I run `fail2ban` on it, with the jail `[dovecot]` enabled. Here is the status of that jail.

```
# fail2ban-client status dovecot
Status for the jail: dovecot
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 5
|  |- Total failed:     94
|  `- File list:        /var/log/mail.warn /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 23
   |- Total banned:     23
   `- Banned IP list:   102.165.49.129 114.220.45.96 115.98.44.72 117.20.117.40 117.81.173.196 117.81.173.227 121.227.161.24 121.239.88.158 180.107.116.92 180.107.125.85 185.137.111.14 185.137.111.145 185.137.111.44 185.137.111.77 185.234.216.120 221.225.183.210 221.225.183.214 221.225.26.196 45.13.36.22 45.227.253.107 49.73.157.152 5.178.153.116 111.94.169.183
```

I have redefined the blocktype from the default `REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` to `DROP`. Here is the output of `iptables -S`.

```
...
-A f2b-dovecot -s 45.13.36.22/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 221.225.26.196/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 221.225.183.214/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 221.225.183.210/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 185.234.216.120/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 185.137.111.77/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 185.137.111.44/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 185.137.111.145/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 185.137.111.14/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 180.107.125.85/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 180.107.116.92/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 121.239.88.158/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 121.227.161.24/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 117.81.173.227/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 117.81.173.196/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 117.20.117.40/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 115.98.44.72/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 114.220.45.96/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-dovecot -s 102.165.49.129/32 -j DROP
...
```

However, I keep getting messages like

```
May 27 22:27:08 mail auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=goldberg@ac.in rhost=185.137.111.77
```

I suppose that IMAP connections is attempted from these banned IP addresses. However, when I manually run

```
iptables -I f2b-dovecot <MY_IP> -j DROP
```

and run

```
telnet MY_MAIL_SERVER 993
```

the packets are dropped as expected.

Question: Why am I still getting `pam_unix(dovecot:auth) authentication failure` messages on my `auth.log`? Aren't connections to the IMAP ports blocked?

Comment: Check the output of `iptables-save -c`. You should investigate where the `-j f2b-dovecot` rule is placed. Order of the rules is very important. Also, check the rule counters. They shouldn't be zero. Otherwise something is wrong - likely some rule above accepts the packets.

Comment: Most of the packets seem to hit the RETURN rule for `f2b-dovecot`. ```[56444:4871959] -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,995,143,993,587,465,4190 -j f2b-dovecot
[63:3152] -A f2b-dovecot -s 115.124.79.18/32 -j DROP
[27:1272] -A f2b-dovecot -s 146.196.108.22/32 -j DROP
[3:152] -A f2b-dovecot -s 102.165.49.129/32 -j DROP
[2859:160096] -A f2b-dovecot -s 45.227.253.107/32 -j DROP
[1291:77314] -A f2b-dovecot -s 185.137.111.14/32 -j DROP
[45757:4263325] -A f2b-dovecot -j RETURN
```

Comment: The iptables rules that fail2ban generates are in the `filter` table; Would it make sense to add them to the `nat` table also? (Is it possible that the `pam_unix` module is called already when the packet is in the `nat` table?